# What is : ASC embedded web server for .net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

From here:
http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/teamlab/TeamLabinstall_EN.pdf

> For a mid-size portal it will be sufficient to deploy it in its default configuration:
>
> - DB : SQLite3
> - Web Server : ASC embedded web server.
>
> Suppose you'll need to deploy the portal on a computer named srv003 to the following folder:
>   c:\teamlab. (these are just example names, so when performing the operation please use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a web server built into the application. In other words you don't need to configure it to use IIS if you don't want to, you just give it a port number and it'll host itself. There are instructions later for hosting under IIS.